# Invoke javascript function (which is in parameter) from native ios code

Tags: javascript, ios

I have javascript function like this.

```
function getState(){
   return "Hello";
}

var cryptico = (function() {

var my = {};

    my.generateRSAKey = function(passphrase, bitlength)
    {
        Math.seedrandom(sha256.hex(passphrase));
        var rsa = new RSAKey();
        rsa.generate(bitlength, "03");
        return rsa;
    }

}());
```

If function is outside, I can easily invoke like this.

```
NSString *jsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cryptico" ofType:@"js"];

NSString *scriptString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
[context evaluateScript:scriptString];

JSValue *test10 = context[@"getState"];
JSValue *test11 = [test10 callWithArguments:@[]]; //will be Hello
```

But how can I call something inside variable? I have tried many different ways but it is not okay.

Answer (score 0):

According to the JSValue Apple Documentation:

An Objective-C block (Swift clousre) and a javascript function should be converted to each other using

```
valueWithObject:inContext:
```

to convert to a JSValue, as you have done in your code, and

```
toObject
```

to convert to its actual type, which is in this case a block. So first try

```
[test10 toObject];
```

and store to a block, then call the block as normal

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on that with code? How can I call "generateRSAKey" ? I think your answer is very close already.